# Maximum Sudoku pencil marks needed

Tags: sudoku

Most Sudoku mobile/video games have a pencil feature which lets you record a candidate in a given cell. Some of these let you pencil in all 9 candidates, and some only a few (3 - 5). The reduction in number of candidates that can be penciled in does not depend on any kid of validation in games that offer it.

I never played a Sudoku game (regardless of difficulty level) where penciling in all 9 numbers as candidates was sensible. In fact, it seems that the row, the column and the region of the target cell would have to all be empty for all 9 numbers to be used as candidates.

What is the realistic/average/probable number of candidates that a cell in Sudoku can have? Is there a way to calculate that based on the difficulty/number of currently filled cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There definitely exist Sudoku having some cell without any eliminations that arise directly from initial clues or from unit propagation of naked singles. Of the 49158 known 17-clue puzzles there are 82 with this property. Here is one example:

`.......51....36.............4.5...8.2.....6.......1.......2.34..1.4..7..6........`

Head over [here](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm), import the puzzle, click Take Step to update the pencilmarks, and you'll see that cell C3 still has 9 candidates.

But if we additionally propagate hidden singles, then none of the 17-clue puzzles has a cell without initial eliminations. This shouldn't be surprising since 17-clue puzzles are generally easy and a large fraction of them are solved entirely after initial propagation of naked and hidden singles.

Here are the actual distributions of initial cell candidate counts across all 17-clue puzzles:

```
# after naked singles only:
     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9
0.23374 0.02876 0.09699 0.20908 0.24695 0.14527 0.03649 0.00269 0.00002

# after naked and hidden singles:
     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9 
0.79189 0.03841 0.05907 0.06201 0.03614 0.01097 0.00145 0.00005 0.00000
```

I'm not sure there's much relationship between this distribution and puzzle difficulty, and it's not even easy to pin down what we mean by difficulty. FWIW, here's the same distribution for a large set of much more difficult puzzles (by the measure of Sudoku Explainer difficulty rating > 11):

```
# after naked singles only:
     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9 
0.30573 0.02490 0.21513 0.27271 0.14950 0.03051 0.00150 0.00002 0.00000 

# after naked and hidden singles:
     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9 
0.31799 0.02526 0.21428 0.26574 0.14559 0.02967 0.00145 0.00002 0.00000
```

Not much difference with/without hidden singles here since the hard puzzles are the very ones that don't allow immediate progress in simple ways.

On a related note, there's an interesting and much less well-studied variation of Sudoku called Pencilmark Sudoku or Sukaku. The rules are exactly the same, except your starting clues are a set of candidate eliminations instead of a set of filled-in cells (i.e., you are given a set of negative literals instead of positive ones). I don't think anyone has proven a lower bound for the number of clues required to determine a unique solution in Pencilmark Sudoku, but it is known that this bound is <= 86, which translates to an average of just over 7.9 remaining candidates per cell. By comparison, 17-clue vanilla Sudoku are positively high-clue puzzles when viewed as Pencilmark Sudoku, since they start with 8*17=136 eliminations in the given cells, but also another 20*17=340 eliminations in cells visible from the given cells (necessarily with some degree of overlap, so not quite 340).